# JQuery Set Property of Input(s) based upon Class Value

Tags: jquery

I have a number of inputs on my page, all of which conform to the following pattern:

```
<label>
<input onchange="checkvals()" name="Segment_" value="OL" id="Segment_8" type="checkbox">
Ocean Line (<span id="ms9" class="detect">0</span>)</label>
```

So label, input, span with a class of "detect" within it, and a value within that span.

I trying to make it so if the item class value of "detect" = 0, it sets the previous input to disabled (and conversely, if greater than zero, makes sure it's enabled).

My jQuery syntax is wrong on the selector/parent .  What ought the correct syntax be?

```
$('.detect').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == '0') {
            $(this).closest('input').prop('disabled', 'true');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

closest looks at itself and the parents. It does not look at siblings.

```
$(this).closest("label").find('input').prop()
```

or

```
$(".detect").siblings("input").prop()
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`.closest` finds ancestor elements, and since the `span` is not *inside* the `input` it does not work.

[Quote from the `.closest` docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and **traversing up through its ancestors** in the DOM tree.

You can, however, find the `label` and then locate the `input`

```
$('.detect').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == '0') {
        $(this).closest('label').find('input').prop('disabled', 'true');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).prev('input').prop('disabled', 'true');
```

This should work, too.

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements.